# Fulltext search on a column with data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search, full-text-search

I have two tables in MySql DB named as 'Patients' and 'Country'.
Patient table contains

`'name','dob',postcode','address', 'country_id'` etc.
 Country table has
`'id' and 'country_name'` columns.

Now, I want the user to enter anything from a patient's name, postcode or country and get the required patient's result/data.

To achieve this, one way that I can think of is to perform the query using joins.
The other way, I wanted to ask was will it be a good approach to store the search variables i.e name, postcode and country in a column with full-text type in a way like this 'name_postcode_country' and when a user enters the search variable I perform the full-text search on the newly created column.

Or there's any other better approach that I should be considering.

Comment: Just join the two tables on the country_id, and in your where clause use **OR** on each of the searchable columns.

Comment: It's much better to keep the data in separate columns than in a merged one. Far easier and more efficient to search.

Comment: Using joins and Like is a better approach than using 'full-text-search'?

Comment: @PashmeenaNoor you should probably use a full-text search on `name`. `postcode` and `country_name` can probably be exact matches.

Comment: @Nick Going for it. Thank you (y)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to hold all those info at a single column, you may use such a combination with a SELECT that JOINs the mentioned tables :

```
select p.name, p.dob, p.postcode, p.address,
       c.country_name
  from Patients p
  inner join Country c 
     on ( p.country_id = c.id )
  where ( upper(name) like upper('%my_name_string%') ) 
     or ( upper(postcode) like upper('%my_postcode_string%') )
     or ( upper(country) like upper('%my_country_string%') );
```

you need to use `upper` or `lower` pseudocolumns against *case-sensitivity* problems.